# Finding the max and min distance between two polygons using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

- I am not able to contain the passing lines till the outer contour, so I can't find the min, and max distances:

[image: Input Image]
[image]

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('Desktop/ImQ5/Image(i).png', 0)
    ret, img =cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_bw = img<=120
    img_bw =img_bw.astype('uint8')
    
    contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( img.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    outer_ellipse = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contours0[0], 0.1, True)]
    inner_ellipse = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contours0[0], 0.1, True)]
    
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    
    vis = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
    
    out=img.copy()
    
    ref = np.zeros_like(img_bw)
    
    cv2.drawContours( vis, outer_ellipse, -1, (255,0,0), 1)
    
    cv2.drawContours( vis, inner_ellipse, -1, (0,0,255), 1)

    cnt_outer = np.vstack(outer_ellipse).squeeze()
    
    cnt_inner = np.vstack(inner_ellipse).squeeze()
    
    ref = np.zeros_like(img_bw)

    # Determine centroid
    
    M = cv2.moments(cnt_inner)
    
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    
    print(cx, cy)
    
    width = img.shape[1]

    height = img.shape[0]
    
    # Define the total number of angles we want
    
    N = 20

    for i in range(N):
    
     tmp = np.zeros_like(img_bw)
    
     theta = i*(360/N)
    
     theta *= np.pi/180.0

    cv2.line(out, (cx, cy),
       (int(cx+np.cos(theta)*w),
         int(cy-np.sin(theta)*h)), (255,0,0), 1)
    
    (row,col) = np.nonzero(np.logical_and(tmp, ref))
     
    cv2.line(out, (cx, cy), (col[0],row[0],(255,0,0), 1))
    
    # Show the image
    
    cv2.imshow('Output', out)
    
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- I am getting this error:

> File "Q5\untitled7.py", line 67, in 
> cv2.line(out, (cx, cy), (row[0],col[0]),(255,0,0), 1)
> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

-**I want that line should be constricted only till the outer contour.
Or crop such as outer lines are not visible**

**I need help with the error I am getting in the above given code.**

Comment: Please format your question properly. Select code with your mouse and click the `{}` button in the formatting toolbar near **Bold** and *Italics*.

Comment: Can you draw (or floodfill) a copy of the largest contour with white against a black background and then use that as the alpha channel which will make the largest contour visible and everything outside of it invisible (black).

Comment: Yeah But basically what i need is the maximum and minimum distance between the two contours and while trying to follow your approach this fails . Well actually in above code i made a function to stop the lines to go through the outermost contour but it doesn't work. I need help with that

Comment: I don't see any functions defined in your code? You also didn't provide your input image...

Comment: Sorry my mistake no function i intended to make one  the image is at topmost line.

Comment: That's a processed image. I meant a separate, un-annotated **input** image from which I can get the contours and process.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this platform, I have put up the image as "Input Image"

Comment: Be sure your coordinates are integers when you feed them to cv2.line()

Comment: OK but what should be the coordinates such that the line from the centroid ends on the outer contour.

Comment: OK but I am just curious that how using my code I can stop lines passing through the outer contour.

Comment: To stop the lines from passing through the outer contour, use the filled outer contour as a mask on your image.

Comment: Okk yes I intended to that but i am not able to implement this in the code

Comment: @AlexCook the idea is that: you have two polygons and you want to measure the **min and the max distance** between them **according to the vectors going from the centroid** inside to the external contour? or you want to measure something special like **Hausdorff Distance** ??

Comment: Yes my approach is to calculate min and max distance with respect to centroid of inside contour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that in Python/OpenCV is to **flood fill** the interior and then get the **distance transform**. *The largest spacing between the two polygons would be twice the maximum value in the distance image.* (The distance between polygons all around is the twice the value of the 'thin' bright ring in the middle of the polygons - the local maximum between the two polygons. So the minimum value between the rings is the lowest value along that 'thin' bright ring.) So the minimum spacing is harder to find. But if we do a **Cartesian to polar transform**, *we can get the maximum values along each row and then find the maximum and minimum values from that.*

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read image
img = cv2.imread('polygons.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# floodfill white between two polygons at 240,240
ffimg = thresh.copy()
ffimg = cv2.floodFill(ffimg, mask, (240,240), 255)[1]

# apply distance transform
distimg = ffimg.copy()
distimg = cv2.distanceTransform(distimg, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)

# Maximum spacing between polygons is 2 * largest value in distimg
max = 2*np.amax(distimg)
print('maximum spacing:', max)

print('')

# convert to polar image using (any) point in the center 'hole' of distimg
polar = cv2.warpPolar(distimg, (360,360), (320,330), 250, cv2.INTER_CUBIC+cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)

# get maximum value along each row
polar_max = np.amax(polar, axis=1)

# find max and min values from row maximum values
max = 2*np.amax(polar_max)
min = 2*np.amin(polar_max)
print('maximum spacing:', max)
print('minimum spacing:', min)

# scale distance image for viewing
distimg = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(distimg, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255))
distimg = distimg.astype(np.uint8)

# scale polar image for viewing
polar = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(polar, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255))
polar = polar.astype(np.uint8)

# save image
cv2.imwrite('polygons_floodfill.png',ffimg)
cv2.imwrite('polygons_distance.png',distimg)
cv2.imwrite('polygons_distance_polar.png',polar)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("floodfill", ffimg)
cv2.imshow("distance", distimg)
cv2.imshow("polar", polar)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Floodfilled image:

[image]

Scaled distance image:

[image]

Scaled polar image:

[image]

Actual (un-scaled) maximum and minimum spacings:

maximum spacing: 158.99530029296875

maximum spacing: 158.77029418945312
minimum spacing: 64.1787109375

Comment: Likewise, you could do a distance transform for the smaller shape, growing up to the image edge, and the read the distance transform values along the larger polygon.

Comment: `@Cris Luengo` Nice idea!